# Let $E:y^2=x^3+17x$. Let $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$($D$ is a negative integer). If $D\neq -17$, I want to prove $E(K)_{tor}\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E:y^2=x^3+17x$.

Let $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$($D$ is a negative integer).
If $D\neq -17$, I want to prove $E(K)_{tor}\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$  a**dmitting the fact that $E(\Bbb{Q})_{tor}\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$**.

If I once could prove $E(K)_{tor}=E(K)[2^∞]$, I can prove $E(K)[2^∞]=E(K)[2]\cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ by explicit calculation.

But how can I prove $E(K)_{tor}=E(K)[2^∞]$ ?

I first came up with trace map. Define $E(K)\to E(\Bbb{Q})$ by $P\to P+P^{\sigma}$ where $\sigma$ is generator of $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, it was typo. $E(K)[2]$ has order $2$ if only if $D\neq -17$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ be a prime. Since $E$ has CM by $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, $a_q(E)=0$, and therefore $E(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})=(q+1)^2$.

Since $E$ has good reduction at $q$, prime-to-$q$ torsion in $E$ reduces injectively mod $q$, so that the prime-to-$q$ part of $E(K)_{tors}$ is a subgroup of $E(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})$, for any quadratic field $K$.

In particular, the cardinality of the prime-to-$3$ part of $E(K)_{tors}$ divides $(3+1)^2=16$, so any torsion in a quadratic number field is either $2$-torsion or $3$-torsion.

In particular, the cardinality of $E(K)_{tors}$ divides $(7+1)^2=64$, so $E(K)_{tors}=E(K)[2^{\infty}]$.

We can also refine this result: take $q=5$. $E$ still has good reduction at $q$ and $a_q(E)=0$, so $E(\mathbb{F}_{25})$ has cardinality $(q+1)^2=36$. In particular, $E(K)[2^{\infty}]$ is a subgroup of $G=E(\mathbb{F}_{25})[2^{\infty}]$, which has order $4$.

Now, $E(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-17}))[2^{\infty}] \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\oplus 2}$, so $G=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\oplus 2}$, and any torsion point defined over a quadratic number field $K$ is a $2$-torsion point.

In particular, if $K \neq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-17})$, then $E(K)_{tors}=E(\mathbb{Q})_{tors}=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Could you tell me why 'having CM by $\Bbb{Q}(i)$ implies $a_q(E)=0$ and $E(\Bbb{F}_{q^2})=(q+1)^2$?

Comment: This should be in most textbooks about elliptic curves, but here’s the argument. First, $|E(\mathbb{F}_{q^2})|=(q+1)^2-a_q(E)^2$, so we just need to show $a_q(E)=0$. On the other hand, for every $x \in \mathbb{F}_q$, $f(x):=x^3-x$ is odd, so either $f(x)=0$ (ie $x=0$ or $x=\pm 1$), or exactly one among $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ is a square. It follows that $y^2=x^3-x$ has exactly $q$ solutions in $\mathbb{F}_q^2$, hence $|E(\mathbb{F}_q)|=q+1$ and $a_q(E)=0$.

Comment: I have a question from the 7-th line from the top. I unrderstand 'Cardinarity of prime-to-7-torsion $E(K)_{tor} $' divides $(7+1)^2=64$ , why can we say cardinality of $E(K)_{tor}$ divides $64$ ?

Comment: Because we just saw that there was no $7$-torsion.